# Is a food ordering menu a good use case for Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, nosql

I have been trying to learn different NoSQL databases so I decided that I want to build a food ordering menu where you can order a burger for example. I want the menu to be able to ask different questions depending on the item being ordered. So for a burger it should ask questions like what kind of bread you want. Should you add extra cheese? Should the patty be hot, mild, extra hot etc. If you order a different item eg a pizza you would have different options from a burger eg what kind of crust you want, what kind of topping to use etc.  Depending on what is being ordered, would you want a side. An item on the menu could either be a main item and could also be a side.

My question is is Neo4j a good database to model this or is there a better database I should be looking at.

Regards

Comment: neo4j is a good choice to model a decision tree, you start with the burger as root node and add a chain of choices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a good choice, because it can model the different aspects flexibly and allow you to make recommendations based on the inputs that users provided.

Here is a nice demo with a restaurant selection in action:

http://www.popotojs.com/

Answer (score 1):

I think Neo4j is good to go with an idea like this. What is nice for me the visualization part which increase the usability of any platform. If you can embed your database with a visualization platform, that would be even better. When you think from social web perspective, you can even recommend food, siders, etc. based on the other customers choices. I suggest you to read the [Graph Databases](http://graphdatabases.com/?_ga=1.177813541.1619132994.1431955276) book to have a broader understanding for your purposes.
For visualization, there are many solutions. I suggest you to have a look [popoto.js example](http://www.popotojs.com/live/factual/index.html), which can give you a perspective how your menu can look like.